# WordPress Custom Post Type Template + Conditional Statements: Any Way to Simplify

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, conditional-statements

So I'm still getting the hang of WordPress Custom Post Types and how to integrate them into an existing template, but I have a quick question about whether the code I've come up with can be simplified?

I have multiple pages I need to call from one particular template, and I've added conditional statements to call each page and its corresponding custom post type code, but I'm essentially repeating most of the code for each conditional statement, so I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this code:

```
            <div class="row">
            <?php if (is_page(165)) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'restaurant',
                    'paged'=>$paged,
                    'orderby'=>'title',
                    'order'=>'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                'taxonomy' => 'restaurant_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'sooke'
                   )
                )
            );
            $restaurants = new WP_Query( $args );
            if( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               while( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               $restaurants->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
               <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
               <?php
                 }
               }
               else {
                echo 'No Restaurants';
               }
               } ?>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
            <?php if (is_page(12)) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'restaurant',
                    'paged'=>$paged,
                    'orderby'=>'title',
                    'order'=>'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                'taxonomy' => 'restaurant_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'chilliwack'
                   )
                )
            );
            $restaurants = new WP_Query( $args );
            if( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               while( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               $restaurants->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
               <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
               <?php
                 }
               }
               else {
                echo 'No Restaurants';
               }
               } ?>
        </div>
```

If there is a way to simplify this code so that I'm not repeating code again and again, I would really appreciate the help to do so, so that I can learn how and how not to create conditional statements with custom post type code in the future. Thanks in advance!

For Dk-Macadamia (updated code that results in white screen)

```
            <?php $terms=array('165'=>'sooke','12'=>'chilliwack');

            //now check it

            if(has_term($terms))
            { ?>
            <div class="row">
                    <?php 
                 foreach($terms as $key=>$val)
                   {
                 if(is_page($key)) {
                         $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'restaurant',
                        'paged'=>$paged,
                        'orderby'=>'title',
                        'order'=>'ASC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'restaurant_category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $val
                            )
                        )
                    ); ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I  think you are looking for [has_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), you can try in in your code as:
Becouse you are working on custom template, so you can set a manually array something like this.

```
$terms=array('165'=>'sooke','12'=>'chilliwack');

//now check it

if(has_term($terms))
{ ?>
<div class="row">
            <?php 
     foreach($terms as $key=>$val)
          {
           if(is_page($key)) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'restaurant',
                    'paged'=>$paged,
                    'orderby'=>'title',
                    'order'=>'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                'taxonomy' => 'restaurant_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $val
                   )
                )
            );
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but I tried plugging it in and it's giving me a blank white page now for the pages with this custom template... any suggestions as to why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

**With the use of switch statements**

```
switch ($slug_name)

case 1 : 'chilliwack'
   my_func('chilliwack');
break;
and so on ....


// here is function

  <?php 
            function my_func($slug) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'restaurant',
                    'paged'=>$paged,
                    'orderby'=>'title',
                    'order'=>'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                'taxonomy' => 'restaurant_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => "$slug"
                   )
                )
            );
            $restaurants = new WP_Query( $args );
            if( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               while( $restaurants->have_posts() ) {
               $restaurants->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
               <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
               <?php
                 }
               }
               else {
                echo 'No Restaurants';
               }
               }
               ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pardon my idiocy as I'm totally new to switch statements, but as with the other answer that was posted, when I add the code in, I get a blank white page outputted when I refresh the pages with this custom template and the new code. I think it's the switch statement as when I omit that, the page is fine, but obviously doesn't output anything. Am I supposed to be wrapping the switch statement in a PHP wrapper? Thanks!

Comment: ofcourse you need to wrap .. for blank page just go to wp-config.php file in your root directory and turn `wp_debug` true, by doing that you will get erros flashing on your page instead of bank page. which is helpful in development. for switch statments refer here .. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php